# Series where more polynomials is added at each step

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

What is the general solution `f(t)` for the following series:

$$f(0) = 1$$
$$f(1) = 1+a$$
$$f(2) = 1+a \cdot b+a \cdot b^2 + a \cdot b^3$$
$$f(3) = 1+a \cdot b+a \cdot b^2 + a \cdot b^3 + a \cdot b^4 + a \cdot b^5 + + a \cdot b^6 + a \cdot b^7$$
$$f(4) = 1+a \cdot b+a \cdot b^2 + a \cdot b^3 + a \cdot b^4 + a \cdot b^5 + + a \cdot b^6 + a \cdot b^7 + a \cdot b^8 + a \cdot b^9 + a \cdot b^{10} + a \cdot b^{11} + a \cdot b^{12} + a \cdot b^{13} + a \cdot b^{14} + a \cdot b^{15}$$
$$f(5) = 1+a \cdot b+a \cdot b^2 + a \cdot b^3 + a \cdot b^4 + a \cdot b^5 + + a \cdot b^6 + a \cdot b^7 + a \cdot b^8 + a \cdot b^9 + a \cdot b^9 + a \cdot b^{10} + a \cdot b^{11} + a \cdot b^{12} + a \cdot b^{13} + a \cdot b^{14} + a \cdot b^{15} + a \cdot b^{16} + a \cdot b^{17} + a \cdot b^{18} + a \cdot b^{19} + a \cdot b^{20} + a \cdot b^{21}+ a \cdot b^{22}+ a \cdot b^{23}+ a \cdot b^{24}+ a \cdot b^{25}+ a \cdot b^{26}+ a \cdot b^{27}+ a \cdot b^{28}+ a \cdot b^{29}+ a \cdot b^{30}+ a \cdot b^{31}$$
$$f(t) = ???$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
f(t) = 1 + a \sum_?^? ??
$$
Fill in the question marks appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the basic idea for solving the question by looking at the highest power of $b$ in each function.
They follow the sequence -

Highest power of $b$ in $f(t)=2^{t-1}-1$

Hence, You can obtain the general expression for $f(t)$ by summing up the geometric progression giving-

$$f(t) = 1+a\cdot b\cdot\frac{b^{2t-1}-1}{b-1}$$

:)